# ssis web service task error

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

Hi i am using a web service which is basically use for sending the mail . For this i am using web service task in SSIS and this service input parameter is text message  in which i am passing a return XML code from execute sql task. when i run my package it's give me below error:

"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:strProdUserDataXML. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 131, position 57.'. Please see InnerException for more details."

One thing i checked if i pass small xml code in text message parameter than it don't gives error.
Please help me how can i increase the size using web service task in ssis

Comment: Did you see this in the error?:   `This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.`    Did you try googling that?

Comment: yes i tried we can do this easily in config file in script task but how i do sam e in web service task??